# CSS Nav menu not clickable on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am trying to help out a friend that made a menu system and it works great in a browser but does not work on a phone. They are using a image as the "menu" button and when I hover over it, the menu drops down as expected.

However, on my phone, i can't really hover over it so it doesn't do anything. If i click it, it also does not do anything. I am figuring this is something silly and easy on my part but I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I know CSS  enough to get most things working but not very good with responsive design yet.

I am sure the issue is in the @media query but I am not seeing what is done wrong.

```css
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  #navbar {
    overflow: visible!important;
  }
  #navwrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('menuicon.png') top left no-repeat;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  #navwrapper ul {
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 310px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  #navwrapper li {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    z-index: 200;
    transition: none;
  }
  #navwrapper ul li:first-child {
    padding: 0!important;
  }
  #navwrapper a:link,
  #navbar a:visited,
  #navbar a:active {
    padding: 0 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #333;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    transition: none;
  }
  #navbar li:hover,
  #navbar li:focus,
  #navbar a:hover,
  #navbar a:focus {
    background: #111;
  }
  #navwrapper:hover {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  #navwrapper:hover ul,
  #navwrapper ul:hover {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navwrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Index</a>
      </li>
      <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li id="link1"><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts or pokes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, hovers and mobile devices simply don't go together. The amount of workarounds (i.e., hacks) needed to get them working simply isn't worth the sacrifice of fragility and maintainability of your code.

You should be able to change the menu to a label with a checkbox to accommodate mobile taps and still add the hover to the label to retain that functionality on desktop. (Yes, this is well-known as a "checkbox *hack* for mobile menus", but it's *much less hackish* than trying to simulate hovers on mobile.)

HTML would then be:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menuBtn">
    <label for="menuBtn"><img src="myMenuButton.png"></label>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li id="link1"><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS to make magic happen:

```
#navbar #menuBtn,
#navbar ul.menu {
    display: none;
}

#navbar #menuBtn:checked ~ ul.menu,
#navbar #menuBtn + label:hover ~ ul.menu {
    display: block;
}
```

This CSS is only for making the menu appear when the `label` is either hovered over (in desktop) or clicked (desktop or mobile). Of course you can split up the second set of rules and wrap them in media queries so the `checked` rule will only apply in a mobile situation if you don't want a desktop user to click the menu and keep it open.

You will also need to integrate your specific styling and positioning CSS rules to the above, but this should get you there from a functional standpoint.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for! Sorry for the delay. I was traveling. I do have one more question about this. How do i make the menu go away when i click the button again or click somewhere else on the screen?

Comment: Nevermind, i actually figured it out. The hover was making it stay. I guess I dont need it as I thought it would be cool. Thanks again for your help @davecripps